Numpy, applying function over several axes
I have trouble to understand how to apply a function over several dimensions of an input array.
For instance, I want to sum the elements in axis 1 and 2. I want to do it doing a custom function (and not the inbuilt .sum() function) to understand what is going on. As a working example
def f(row, axis = 0):
    return np.sum(row, axis)

b = np.random.randint(6, size = (100, 101, 102))
c = np.apply_over_axes(f, b, axes = [1,2])
c.shape


When running this, I get the output dimension (100, 1, 1). Running instead b.sum(axis=(1,2))I get output dimension (100,) (which is what I want). Here, I also do not understand why I need to add the axis argument in the function f, if I do not add it there is an error.
Further, I would like to understand how to apply a custom function over several axis. For instance, getting the second largest element. I do not believe this is possible applying a function recursively over several axes, how would I have to proceed?
Thanks!

That apply... function is written in python,so you can easily see what it's doing.  It expands dims at each recursive step so axis '2' remains the same. It's easy to 'squeeze' out the extra dimensions after.

The details of how functions like np.sum take multiple axes are hidden in compiled code.  I suspect it reshapes the input and then does the single axis reduction.  I don't think the order of the axes matters.  With apply... the application is sequential and axes order could matter.

Do you know how to apply your function over one axis?  Why not just apply it sequentially to each axis?  This isn't the place to worry about 'efficiency'. You may need to ask a new question with a clear example with this 'custom' function.

apply_over_axes() applies the function sequentially to each specified axis, and it preserves the original dimensionality by keeping singleton dimensions for the axes it operates on - numpy.apply_over_axes
For your scenario you can try np.sum() with a tuple of axes
c_simplified = b.sum(axis=(1,2))
print(c_simplified.shape)

In a Picture
import numpy as np
b = np.random.randint(6, size=(100, 101, 102))

result_sum = b.sum(axis=(1, 2))  

result_max = b.max(axis=(1, 2)) 

result_mean = b.mean(axis=(1, 2))

output#
Sum shape: (100,)
Max shape: (100,)
Mean shape: (100,)

Edit 1:
f: Specifies the axis along which np.sum operates. Without it, the function cannot correctly sum over the intended axis.
axes parameter in np.apply_over_axes: Specifies the axes over which the function f should be applied iteratively, reducing them to size 1.
The axis parameter in your function f is necessary because np.sum needs to know which axis to operate on. Without it, the function call will fail, as np.sum defaults to summing over all axes if axis isn't specified, which conflicts with the iterative application of np.apply_over_axes
More can be found at - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html
Summing Over Axes 1 and 2
import numpy as np

def custom_sum(array, axes):
 
    axes = tuple(axes)
    return np.sum(array, axis=axes)

b = np.random.randint(6, size=(100, 101, 102))
c = custom_sum(b, axes=(1, 2))
print(c.shape)  

output
(100,)

Second Largest Element Over Axes 1 and 2
you can reshape the array, sort along the flattened axes
axes = tuple(axes)
flattened = np.reshape(array, (-1,) + array.shape[len(axes):])
sorted_array = np.sort(flattened, axis=1)
print(sorted_array[:, -2])


Thanks for your answer. However I am not interested in applying the in-built .sum() function, I want to understand what is going on (so that I can apply other functions as well)

Edited...pls have  alook

Thanks! For your second answer for the second largest element: I would really like to apply an "efficient" custom function to find the second largest element (trivially, this is done in O(n) time and O(1) space, sorting takes O(n\log(n)) time).
